# Splitting class with too many attributes - angular

Tags: angular, class, split

I got a typescript class which has many attributes (in total 22). There are some booleans. Depending on them other attributes can/can't be set by user. Im using reactiveForms.
Each boolean enables 5 other attributes. Any suggestion how to split this (create new classes,OR combine classes OR OR OR) in a more angular readable/clean way? Because I got the feeling a class with 22 arguments is to much.

... snipped

```
constructor({
  id, name, description, itemIds, price = 0, limited = false, total = 0,
  remaining = 0, date = new Date(), frequently = false, weekday = 1, 
  monthDay = 1, interval = "daily", startTime = { "hour": 0, "minute": 0 },
  endTime = { "hour": 0, "minute": 0 }, intervalOptions = {} 
}: { 
  id: number; name: string;
  description: string; itemIds: number[]; price?: number; limited?: boolean;
  total?: number; remaining?: number; date?: Date; frequently?: boolean;
  weekly?: boolean; weekday?: number; monthly?: boolean; monthDay?: number;
  interval?: string; startTime?: {}; endTime?: {}; intervalOptions?: {};
})
```

Comment: You can may be split them inside services in which every service is responsible for a set related properties, afterward you can use dependency injection and inject the services you created in this type script class.
But really you don't have to split just because it is big.

Comment: Ask yourself is this class responsible for just one thing? If not create another. I can see a possible date class. Favor composition means instead of individual parms you can pass in class models. Like cart, and date class.